# Find cell in another tab

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is a multi-part question: I'm at a loss to explain it succinctly in one clear statement. I'll try to clean it up after getting some feedback:

1. In Google Docs, I would like to search a different tab (in the same spreadsheet) to find a cell which contains specific data. The data may be moved around, making it impossible to use a static cell reference.

   //if 'Sheet2' of my spreadsheet contains the following...
        A    B    C    D
   1    -    -    -    -
   2    -    foo  bar  6
   3    -    -    -    -

   //...then some magical function would return C2
   =getCell( 'Sheet2', "bar" )
2. Now that we've got this cell, I want to get the values of the adjacent cells on the same row.

   //this would return "foo":
   =getLeft( getCell( 'Sheet2', "bar" ) )

   //and this would return 6
   =getRight( getCell( 'Sheet2', "bar" ) )

I was able to get a function working that satisfies the above task. However, it is PAINFULLY SLOW! I'm using the function in about 100+ places, so this makes the sheet timeout on calculation every time I change something.

Can anyone suggest how to get the same functionality, but with much better performance?

```
function getCell( sheetname, item, row_offset, default_string )
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastcol = sheet.getLastColumn();
  for( var c = 1; c <= lastcol; c++ )
  {
    for( var r = 1; r <= lastrow; r++ )
    {
      var range = sheet.getRange(r, c);
      if( range.getValue() == item )
      {
        //item found! See if we can get the requested cell...
        c = c + row_offset;  //adjust column using given offset
        if( c < 1 || c > lastcol )
          return "E.offset";
        else
          return sheet.getRange(r,c).getValue();
      }
    }
  }
  return default_string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you add a row and a column before your data range as follows:

```
     A    B    C    D    E    F    G
1                                  "bar"
2         -    -    -    -         
3         -    foo  bar  6
4         -    -    -    -
```

You have a cell where you have the cell content you are looking for, let's say in G1. In cell A2 you place the formula:

```
=COUNTIF(B2:E2,$G$1)
```

Which will check row A for the a match on the cell G1. Fill down the other cells in row A and cell A3 will show "1".

Use a similar formula for cell B1:

```
=COUNTIF(B2:B4,$G$1)
```

And fill across the row. Cell D1 will show a 1.

Then, use INDEX() with MATCH() to find the contents of the cells on either side:

Left:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$E$4,MATCH(1,$A$2:$A$4,0),MATCH(1,$B$1:$E$1,0)-1)
```

Right:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$E$4,MATCH(1,$A$2:$A$4,0),MATCH(1,$B$1:$E$1,0)+1)
```

No scripting required!